# Problem in accesing serial port

Tags: pi-3, serial

I am trying to get access to the /dev/ttyS0 file in an attempt to interface sim808 to the RPi via TX and RX connection.  However, when I am in the /dev directory, when I type in /dev/ttyS0 I get the message: "Permission denied." How do I overcome this problem? Can you please guide me on how to solve this issue. 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/omaBh.jpg)[image]

Comment: Not Pi specific.

Comment: What model of RPi?

Answer (score 2):

Something is already using the device.  That's why the listing shows a device group of tty rather than dialout.

There is possibly a console login via the device or the device is being used for kernel boot messages.

If you are using Raspbian you can disable such usage with `sudo raspi-config`.

Answer (score 0):

Either it is already in  use or you can use `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600 parodd` 
You can also check in `sudo raspi-config`